# Is there an adjective that means "fly, floats and travels in the air"?

Tags: word-request

I am thinking about how the seeds of plants often floats and travel by air, and I am pretty sure there's an adjective just for that, but I don't remember it. Dandelion seeds is an example of a thing that flies, floats and travels in the air.

For example:

> Dandelion seeds are ___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dandelion seeds are **Airborne**

Definition --

```
airborne
/ˈɛːbɔːn/
adjective

    transported by air.
    "airborne pollutants"
        (of an aircraft) in the air after taking off.
        "the shuttle was airborne"
        synonyms:   flying, in flight, in the air, on the wing, winging; More
        gliding, hovering, soaring
        "the shuttle was airborne"
```